# Pyomo (v5.2) python(v3.7) script solving concrete model throws ValueError: No objective defined; cannot write legal LP file

Tags: python, pyomo

I've built a pyomo concrete model and am trying to run it using a python script (Pyomo version 5.2 with python 3.7). When I try solving the model by running:

```
opt = SolverFactory('glpk')
results = opt.solve(model)
results.write()
```

then I get this error:

> ValueError: ERROR: No objectives defined for input model;  cannot
>   write legal LP file

Interstingly I know the objective rule works. When I run `Objective_rule(model)` I get a value back, and I can also manually change the model variables by assigning them different values, such as:

```
model.system_capacity = 1000
```

with the return value from the objective rule changing in response.

Any thoughts? I'm pretty new to pyomo and Algebraic Modeling Languages (AMLs) in general.

Here's my model, simplified:

```
# pyomo model for fitting historical solar generation profile to PVWatts simulation
# initialize input parameters
system_capacity_init = 1.0
lims = [0.2, 3.0]
system_capacity_bounds = (system_capacity_init * lims[0], system_capacity_init * lims[1])
# define and initialize integer parameters
# module type
module_type_dict = {0: 'Standard', 1: 'Premium', 2: 'ThinFilm'}
module_type_vals = list(module_type_dict.keys())
module_type_index_init = 0
# initialize pyomo concrete model
model = ConcreteModel()
# define continuous variables
model.system_capacity = Var(initialize=system_capacity_init, 
                            bounds=system_capacity_bounds,
                            domain=PositiveReals)
# define integer variables
# module type
model.module_type_vals = Set(initialize=module_type_vals)
model.module_type = Var(initialize=module_type_vals[module_type_index_init], 
                        within=model.module_type_vals)
# define objective function
def Objective_rule(model):
    """get hourly modeled solar roduction from PVWatts5 simulation tool using hourly historical solar insolation
    defined in filename_solar comparing against hourly historical date in hourlysettlementdata"""
    system_capacity = value(model.system_capacity)
    module_type = value(model.module_type)
    hourlypvwatts = sf.gethourlysolarproduction(filename_solar, folder, 
            system_capacity, module_type)
    leastsquared = np.sum((hourlypvwatts[:8760] - hourlysettlementdata[:8760])**2)
    return float(leastsquared)
# when passed function named as _rule then automatically assigns as rule, defaulte sense=minimize
model.Objective = Objective()
# examine model
model.pprint()
```

And here's the pprint / model declaration (again I cut out some variables so it is shorter...):

```
1 Set Declarations
    module_type_vals : Dim=0, Dimen=1, Size=3, Domain=None, Ordered=False, Bounds=(0, 2)
        [0, 1, 2]

2 Var Declarations
    module_type : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :     0 :     0 :     2 : False : False : module_type_vals
    system_capacity : Size=1, Index=None
        Key  : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
        None :  12.0 :  60.0 : 180.0 : False : False : PositiveReals

1 Objective Declarations
    Objective : Size=0, Index=None, Active=True
        Key : Active : Sense : Expression

12 Declarations: system_capacity dc_ac_ratio inv_eff losses tilt azimuth gcr module_type_vals module_type array_type_vals array_type Objective
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You didn't call objective rule in the objective definition. You can find an example here https://software.sandia.gov/downloads/pub/pyomo/PyomoOnlineDocs.html#_objectives

Comment: Calling the objective explicitly is definitely more clear, but calling the objective rule Objective_rule automatically declares the rule, and you can also see the pprint model declaration has picked up the rule.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, you didn't pass in the objective function rule when declaring your objective function. Your objective function declaration should be:

```
model.Objective = Objective(rule=Objective_rule)
```

The other issue I see is that your objective function rule doesn't look like it depends on any of the variables in the model and will be a fixed float value the way it is currently written. Remember that the objective function rule is not a call-back function that is evaluated multiple times by the solver. The objective function rule should return an algebraic expression involving Pyomo variables.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much. Regarding declaring the objective, you way is more clear, but calling the rule by the name Objective_rule automatically declares the rule. I think your second point may be more relevant. I am basically trying to do least squared optimization with a mixed integer variable. The variables model.system_capacity and model.module_type are continuous and an integer set, respectively, and are used in the objective function. But I was imagining the objective function would be evaluated for each selection of model parameters in order to minimize the objective function.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to post this as a comment to @bethany-nicholson, but there is enough additional information to warrant an additional answer.

First, the answer about returning an expression instead of a computed value (i.e., rules generate expressions and are not callbacks) is spot-on and correct.

The remainder of this answer targets the use of "implicit rules".  While older versions of Pyomo supported "implicit rules" (i.e., a component `foo` automatically looking for and using a `foo_rule()` if no rule was explicitly provided), that behavior was deprecated in Pyomo 4.0, and the developers threatened to remove it completely in Pyomo 5.0 (although as of 5.5 the functionality - with deprecation warning - is still there).

That said, it appears that implicit rules have *never* worked for `Objective` components (the implicit rule functionality was built into the Block component, and relied on rules being stored as a `_rule` attribute in the Component ... and Objective uses `rule` instead of `_rule`).  This fragility is in part why support for implicit rules was deprecated.

If you are looking for a concise notation for specifying models, you might consider the component decorator notation:

```
@model.Objective()
def obj(m):
    return # expression defining the objective
```

This creates an Objective component and attaches it to the `model` object using the name `obj`, assigning the `obj()` function as the component's rule.